# Как вывести рандомные переменные JS

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

У меня есть много разных фруктов. Апельсин, Банан, Яблоки...
Мне нужно, чтобы JS рандомно выдавал каждому человеку по фрукту. 
Код выглядит так:

```
var name, fruit1, fruit2, fruit3

fruit1 = ("Апельсин");
fruit2 = ("Банан");
fruit3 = ("Яблоки");

name = prompt("Введите Ваше имя")
document.write(name+" "+RandomFruit)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вместо *RandomFruit* подставляло рандомный фрукт?

Comment: Каждый должен получить свой фрукт или возможны повторения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно вас понял, то примерно вот так. Есть, конечно, небольшой изврат) Но куда без него XD

```
var name, fruits, number;

fruits = [
    'Апельсин',
  'Банан',
  'Яблоки',
  'Апельсин',
  'Любой фрукт'
];

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
number = getRandom(0, fruits.length);

name = prompt("Введите Ваше имя");


document.write(name +" "+ fruits[parseInt(number)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.randomItem = function() {
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)];
}

const fruits = [
  'Апельсин',
  'Банан',
  'Яблоко'
];

console.log(fruits.randomItem());
```